# Model generation for large-sized instances

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, job-shop-scheduling

I have a scheduling model where each job $p$ requires three operations (with fixed precedence and they must happen in a row) for a fixed number of $i$ service sessions (each session on a specific day). The service duration for operations of job $p$ is equal to $S^1_p$, $S^2_p$, and $S^3_p$. An identical machine $n$ can serve multiple jobs at the same time slot $j$ and day $t$, but not two jobs within their first operations, third operations, and first and third operations. In other words, a machine can handle multiple jobs at the same time within their second operations ($S^2_p$), but only one of jobs can be within their first or third operations:

[image]

where $a_{pjti}$ is a binary variable indicating job $p$ starts at time slot $j$ on day $t$ for service session $i$, and $y_{pnti}$ is a binary variable indicating job $p$ is being allocated to machine $n$ on day $t$ for its service session $i$.

I have used these constraints in my MILP model and coded it in python (shown below). However, for large-sized instances, it takes one day to generate each of the above constraint sets (on a powerful computer). Do you have any suggestions on how I can implement these constraints?

[image]

Comment: It takes a day just to generate the constraints (without attempting to solve the model)? What are your dimensions?

Comment: Yes, it takes a day to generate the constraints! $|\mathcal{P}|=150$, $|\mathcal{C}|=3$, $|\mathcal{N}_c|=10$, $|\mathcal{J}|=32$, $|\mathcal{T}|=28$, $|\mathcal{I}|=5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest three major changes:

1. Omit the $y$ variables.
2. Replace the $a_{p,j,t,i}$ variables with $a_{p,j,t,i,n}$.
3. Instead of pairs of jobs, consider much larger subsets of jobs.

The resulting reformulation will have fewer and stronger constraints, all of the form
$$\sum_{p,j,t,i} a_{p,j,t,i,n} \le 1 \quad \text{for all $\bar{j},\bar{t},n$},$$
where the summation is over all $(p,j,t,i)$ for which job $p$ starting in slot $j$ on day $t$ for service session $i$ would be in its first or third operation in slot $\bar{j}$ and day $\bar{t}$.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding! Each job requires multiple service sessions, each on a day. Each service session includes the so-called three operations. I will be implementing sth very similar to your suggestion and will evaluate its impact. Anyhow, thank you for the help!

Comment: I think you might have caught me in the model of an edit.  The latest update captures that.

Comment: I can see how your constraint set is working now! However, it needs a minor modifications: $\sum_{p,i,j} a_{pjtin} \leq 1,  \forall j^{'}, t, n$ where $j^{'}$ is those time slots that job $p$ is in its first or third operations. Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad to help.  How long does it take to generate the new constraints?

Comment: @RobPratt Using the dimensions in the answer to my comment, I get about 1.3 million binary variables in the original formulation and about 20.2 million with your formulation. I'll be curious to see if this ends up faster.

Comment: @prubin How do the constraint counts compare?

Comment: My problem includes several constraints. The problem that I am aiming to solve is also large. With my previous way of modeling, it could generate small-sized instances pretty fast, but it could take days to find the optimal solution. With your way of solving, for a small-sized instance, it took almost nothing to generate the model and find the optimal solution. For large-sized instances (e.g., the aforementioned instance), it took around 1,000 secs to generate the model using your molding approach, and a few seconds to find the optimal solution. Let me know if you want further information!

Comment: @RobPratt I suspect there are fewer constraints, but I couldn't tell -- my eyes watered every time I tried to read the model. :-) Apparently your approach worked gangbusters.

Comment: In fact, using your approach helped me to simplify the abovementioned constraint sets and simplify several other constraint sets. Your approach creates more variables, but much much fewer constraints. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear that this worked well!